# Disable specific plugins for unlogged users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment-method

I am trying to disable [WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/) for unlogged users. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - The following will disable Paypal Checkout Payment gateway for unlogged users:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditionally_disable_paypal_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
function conditionally_disable_paypal_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways; // Only on frontend

    // Loop through payment gateways
    foreach( $available_gateways as $gateways_id => $gateways ){
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $gateways_id === 'ppec_paypal' ) {
            unset($available_gateways[$gateways_id]);
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> For Woocommerce default Paypal payment gateway, replace `'ppec_paypal'` by `'paypal'`.